# how to set directory of the System.setOut()

Tags: java, eclipse, run-configuration

I want to save my output as a separate at a specified folder. The following code would save the output at the project root. How can I change it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(f));
      System.out.println("This is System class!!!");
}
```

Besides, I have tried to change the "Run Configurations"-> "Common"-> "Output File" in Eclipse, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: ```System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/my/absolute/path/comes/here.txt"))))``` should work. But routing sysout to a file is usually bad at application level. You usually do it with a redirect in the shell that launch it, like ```$ java Pouet > myfile.txt```

Comment: And if you are implementing some kind of logging system using ```System.out.println``` this is really ugly. Have a look at SLF4J and Logback for example, which is way more sofisticated combo: you can log to console, to files, to email, bridge different logging system to the one of your choice, change pattern, etc... In real professional world, this is a requirement in every project. See https://logback.qos.ch/ and https://www.slf4j.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intead of passing directly the Filename to the FileOutputStream you need to pass it a File instance like this:

```
File directoryLogs = new File("logs");
fileDirectory.mkdirs(); // Create the directory (if not exist)

File fileLog = new File(directoryLogs, "log.txt");
fileLog.createNewFile(); // Create the file (if not exist)
```

then

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Create a log directory
    File directoryLogs = new File("logs");
    fileDirectory.mkdirs();

    // Create a log file
    File fileLog = new File(directoryLogs, "log.txt");
    fileLog.createNewFile();

    // Create a stream to to the log file
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(fileLog);

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(f));
    System.out.println("This is System class!!!");

    // You should close the stream when the programs end
    f.close();
}
```

If you want completly change the path of logs directory you could also specify
an absolute path here

```
// NB: Writing directly to C:\ require admin permission
File directoryLogs = new File("C:\\MyApplication\\logs");
```